# python function that creates HTML for a row containing two cells

Tags: python, html

I'm looking to write a function in python that accepts a dictionary and a single key as parameters in order to create HTML for a row containing two cells. I'd like the cells to contain a key/value pair from the dictionary.

the dictionary -

```
d = {'year':1999, 'director':'Mike Judge', 'title':'Office Space'}
```

my guess at what the function might look like;

```
def makeHTMLRow(d, 'title'):
s = <table border ="1">\n
s = s + "<tr>\n"
s = s + "\t<td> row 1, cell 1</td>\n"
s = s + "\t<td> row 1, cell 2</td>\n"
s = s + "</tr>"
s = s + "<tr>\n"
s = s + "\t<td> row 2, cell 1</td>\n"
```

Is this the right direction to go in?

I'd like to use my Python  code on Google App Engine, which is why I'm writing HTML in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you written is OK, but you can make it more concise:

```
def makeHTMLRow(d, 'title'):
    s =  "<tr>\n\t"
    s += "<td>%(year)d</td>\n\t"
    s += "<td>%(director)s</td>\n"
    s += "</tr><tr>\n\t"
    s += "<td>%(title)s></td>\n"
    s += "</tr>"
    return s % d
```

This sample uses python string formatting with dictionary.

Comment: thanks, I was a bit unsure on how to actually use the dictionary (no different than typical dictionary usage) and you answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

And the question is? If you have no permission for installing arbitrary code on a hosted environment you have to write yourself. Or you re-use existing modules like

http://www.pasko.net/PyHtmlTable/

(Google is your friend)